# Ajuda com COUNT mysql e Asp Net Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

No meu sistema tenho um formulario para abertura de chamados, no qual cada chamado tem os seguintes status: `Aberto`, `Agendado`, `Em Atendimento` e `Finalizado`.

Gostaria de exibir na *home* a quantidade de cada um dos chamados atualmente, para isso criei o seguinte script do mysql:

```
string sql = "SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) AS quantidade FROM chamados GROUP BY STATUS";
```

No mysql recebo o retorno correto, por exemplo :

> 3 Aberto
>   2 Em atendimento
>   1 Agendado
>   1 Finalizado

Minha duvida agora e como usando o .Net Core eu consigo exibir esse registro em minha *home*.

Conforme solicitado pelos colegas, segue meu problema melhor detalhado:
Na print abaixo tenho esses cards onde gostaria de exibir a contagem de registros feitos com cada tipo de status:

[image: Card da minha Home]

A conexão com o Banco de dados ja foi feita, faz o insert, update e delete normalmente, o problema esta em como fazer para que minha query sql retorne as contagens e consiga exibir isso na Home.

No Model usei o seguinte código (So adicionei a query mesmo)

```
 public void Contagem()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) AS quantidade FROM chamados GROUP BY STATUS";
    }
```

Ai preciso gravar isso em alguma variavel e depois exibir essa variável na minha Index.

```
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="small-box bg-green">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3>40</h3> //Aqui iria retornar a quantidade de chamados em atendimento

          <p>Chamados em Atendimento</p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-headset"></i>
        </div>
        <a href="~/Chamados/Index" class="small-box-footer">Ver todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Arquivo DAL de conexão com o Banco de Dados

```
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace HelpDesk.Uteis
{
    public class DAL 
    {
        private static string Server = "localhost";
        private static string Database = "helpdesk";
        private static string User = "root";
        private static string Password = "root";
        private static string ConnectionString = $"Server={Server};Database={Database};Uid={User};Pwd={Password};Sslmode=none;Charset=utf8;";

        private static MySqlConnection Connection;

        public DAL()
        {
            Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
        }

        //Espera um parâmetro do tipo string 
        //contendo um comando SQL do tipo SELECT
        public DataTable RetDataTable(string sql)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command);
            da.Fill(data);
            return data;
        }

        //Espera um parâmetro do tipo string 
        //contendo um comando SQL do tipo INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
        public void ExecutarComandoSQL(string sql)
        {
            MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(sql, Connection);
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá João, tente postar o que você já conseguiu fazer, na sua pergunta não conseguimos nem ter a ideia se você já configurou o banco de dados em seu projeto. Abraço.

Comment: João como o Bruno Soares disse não da pra saber em qual etapa você está tendo duvidas, tente esclarecer um pouco melhor. Abraço.

Comment: @BrunoSoares  Editei minha duvida tentando detalhar melhor. A conexão com o banco de dados ja foi feita e funciona normalmente, estou começando meus estudos em .net core e não estou conseguindo criar uma lógica para fazer com que uma query de contagem me retorne o valor em uma variavel que possa colocar em meu índex, exibindo assim nesse caso a contagem de quantos registros foram feitos em cada status.

Comment: @João você ta usando algum ORM? Essa consulta é realizada como? ADO.NET? Dapper? Entity Framework? Com o que você colocou é possível saber apenas que você tem uma string armazenando o SQL da consulta

Comment: @Vinícius adicionei o meu código de conexão, a string SQL que fiz foi como eu consulto no banco de dados para ter o retorno da contagem de registro feitos em cada Status, se tiver uma maneira melhor ou mais correta de fazer isso no .Net Core e puder compartilhar pode modificar =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um objeto que receba essas 2 informações e depois mande ela para a View

Model

```
public class ObjStatus
{
    public int quantidade{get; set;}
    public string status {get; set;}
}
```

Repositorio

```
public class RpoStatus 
{
    ...
    //Se for uma lista usar List<ObjStatus>, se for somente popular objeto usar ObjStatus e troque .ToList() para .FirstOrDefault()
    public List<ObjStatus> mtdListarStatus(){
        string sql = "SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) AS quantidade FROM chamados GROUP BY STATUS";
        return dbContext.Database.SqlServer<ObjStatus>(sql).ToList();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
ObjStatus obj = new ObjStatus();
RpoStatus rpo = new RpoStatus();
obj = rpo.mtdListarStatus();
return View(obj);
```

View (Edite conforme necessidade)

```html
 @model.namespace.ObjStatus

// Se for uma lista, fazer o foreach, caso contrario desta forma:
<div class="inner">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.quantidade) 
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.staus)
</div>
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.